# Hypothesis on a parameter to ensure the unique solvability of a modified Laplace equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, cauchy-problem

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^3$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain, $n$ the normal vector on its boundary and $q\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. I want to find the minimal hypothesis on $q$ such that the following system has a unique solution in $H^1(\Omega)$ :
$$
\begin{cases}
(-\Delta + q) v= f&\mbox{ in }\Omega\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}=0&\mbox{ on }\partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
where $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is a given data.

If we choose $q>0$ on $\Omega$, we obtain the result using the Lax-Milgram Lemma. But what if $q$ is not positive?